# How did Thor get healed?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

When Thor was in the Guardians' spaceship in *Avengers: Infinity War* he has his eye back.

Where did this eye come from?

Comment: Was the title changed to its current form to avoid spoilers? Its currently utterly information-free, which seems like a bad title to me. But a mod did it, so presumably there's a good reason.

Comment: The new title doesn't change the minor spoiler, there.. had to lose it to get it back

Comment: The title does not match the question. *Where* did he get his eye back. Not *How*.

Comment: What should we ask next. From where did Thor get his new Axe?

Comment: @KharoBangdo "Where did Thor get a change of clothes (if he did)?"

Comment: The only time Thor was on Guardians' spaceship and had both eyes was immediately after he received it (about a minute of screen time). The origin of the eye was explained in the same scene. I don't understand the point of this question.

Comment: Is OP asking to avoid having to go see the movie?  Generally people ask about events that happened, and there really is no mystery or explanation required for this part.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Rocket Raccoon gave Thor a new eye ball to replace his missing one.**

> Rocket: Well, if fate does want you to kill that crapsack, you’re
>   gonna need more than one stupid eyeball.
>
> Thor: What's this?
>
> Rocket: What's it look like? Some jerk lost a bet with me in
>   Contraxia.
>
> Thor: He gave you his eye?
>
> Rocket: No, he gave me 100 credits. I snuck in his room later that
>   night and stole his eye.

We know from both Guardians of the Galaxy volumes 1 and 2 that Rocket has a thing for keeping other people's body parts; in part 1 he gets another inmates prosthetic leg, and in part 2 he wants to keep an eyeball that Groot accidentally brought to him, simply because he thinks it is funny. He also mentions in Infinity War that he wants Bucky's arm.

While it is possible that the eyeball in Infinity War is the same one from Guardians of the Galaxy Volume 2, I do not think that this is likely; because Rocket states where he got the eyeball, and that story is not what happened in Volume 2. It does not seem likely that he would be lying. He admits to having stolen the eyeball, so why would he lie about who he stole it from and where?

Also, the eyeball that is stolen in Volume 2 is green; while the eyeball he gives Thor in Infinity War appears to be blue.

Comment: Rocket seems like the kind of .. er ... *being*, who would totally lie about that kind of thing if he thought it made for a better story. In G2 he was constantly making up stories (and winking with the wrong eye).

Answer (score 14):

That could be [Vorker](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Vorker)'s eye which was stolen by Baby Groot because of  mis-communication in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*:

So I assumed it's Vorker's eye which Rocket Raccoon gave a  to Thor in *Avengers: Infinity War* but this one is of different colour then Vorker's eye and if we believe Rocket then it can be some other person's eye he stole from Contraxia, here is the scene from it:

And having that eyepatch was not as easy as it seems, as said by Chris himself:

> It was... yeah, I remembered being... with the eyepatch, the story unrolling, 'Yeah, cool, this is interesting.' And then the day that we put the eyepatch on I was like, 'This is ridiculous.' The thing kept falling off, and we didn't have the thing [gestures an eyepatch strap]. So it became a CG eyepatch, which I was stoked about... But I'm happy with that trade [for the wig]. It has its downsides. But the upside is that it's an hour less in hair and makeup without the wig on.- [cinemablend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1827099/chris-hemsworth-reveals-something-very-cool-about-his-avengers-infinity-war-eyepatch)

So they don't have to do that CGI eyepatch anymore.

Comment: Do we know this? Yes we see Rocket steal an eyeball in Guardians Vol 2, but he says in Infinity War that the eye was won in a bet in a different place. He certainly could be lying, but I thought it was just a different eyeball from a different place. We know from vol 1 and 2 that Rocket likes to collect body parts.

Comment: I was pretty sure that Rocket said in the movie that he'd won a bet with someone for a hundred credits (or similar), Thor asked if the loser paid with the eye, and Rocket said no, that he'd stolen it that night after breaking into the loser's place?

Comment: Rocket: Some jerk lost a bet with me in Cotraccia(sp). 

Thor: He gave you his eye?

Rocket: No, he gave me 100 credits. I snuck in his room later that night and stole his eye.

Comment: It's still a different story, in a different location, than what happened in Guardians Vol 2. So either he was lying, or it's not the same eye.

Comment: If this answer is true, apart from lying, Rocket must have been fiddling with it, since the color of the eye changed from green to blue.

Comment: @xDaizu updated the answer

Answer (score 13):

If you are asking about the eye, it's not Thor's eye... It was just an eye that Rocket lent to Thor based on this [dialogue](https://www.moviequotesandmore.com/avengers-infinity-war-best-quotes/)...

> Rocket: Well, if fate does want you to kill that crapsack, you’re going to need more than one stupid eyeball.
>
> [he gives Thor an eyeball]
>
> Thor: What’s this?
>
> Rocket: What’s it look like? Some jerk lost a bet with me in Contraxia.
>
> Thor: He gave you his eye?
>
> Rocket: No, he gave me a hundred credits. I snuck into his room later that night and stole his eye.
>
> Thor: Thank you, sweet rabbit.
>
> [Thor puts the eyeball into his empty eye socket]
>
> Rocket: Ooh. I would’ve washed that. The only way I could sneak it off Contraxia was on my…

This also explains the origins of the eye where Rocket "acquired" said eye from a bet...

Comment: ...off Contraxia was IN my...